[React Flow]: Couldn't create edge for source handle id: "null", edge id: e_user_id_order
I want to create a sample database scheme. For some reason when I try to use custom nodes, instead of default ones I get error stating [React Flow]: Couldn't create edge for source handle id: "null", edge id: e_user_id_order. in my console and nodes does not show up.
Here is my code, I tried to put it as simple as possible:

const CustomNode = ({ data, id }) => {
    return (
        <div
            style={{
                border: '1px solid #777',
                padding: '10px',
                borderRadius: '5px',
            }}
        >
            <h3 style={{ margin: 0 }}>{data.title}</h3>
            <ul style={{ padding: 0, margin: 0, listStyle: 'none' }}>
                {data.fields.map((field, index) => (
                    <li key={`${id}-${index}`}>{field}</li>
                ))}
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
};

const initialNodes = [
    {
        id: 'table1',
        position: { x: 0, y: 0 },
        data: { title: 'Users', fields: ['user_id', 'username', 'email'] },
        type: 'custom',
    },
    {
        id: 'table2',
        position: { x: 300, y: 0 },
        data: { title: 'Orders', fields: ['order_id', 'user_id (FK)', 'product_id (FK)'] },
        type: 'custom',
    },
    {
        id: 'table3',
        position: { x: 600, y: 0 },
        data: { title: 'Products', fields: ['product_id', 'product_name'] },
        type: 'custom',
    },
];

const initialEdges = [
    {
        id: 'e_user_id_order',
        source: 'table1',
        target: 'table2',
        label: 'user_id joins user_id (FK)',
        style: { stroke: '#f00' },
    },
    {
        id: 'e_product_id_order',
        source: 'table3',
        target: 'table2',
        label: 'product_id joins product_id (FK)',
        arrowHeadType: 'arrowclosed',
    },
];

export default function DatabaseScheme() {
    const [nodes, setNodes, onNodesChange] = useNodesState(initialNodes);
    const [edges, setEdges, onEdgesChange] = useEdgesState(initialEdges);

    const onConnect = useCallback(
        (params) => setEdges((eds) => addEdge(params, eds)),
        [setEdges],
    );

    const nodeTypes = {
        custom: CustomNode,
    };

    return (
        <div style={{ width: '80vw', height: '80vh' }}>
            <ReactFlow
                nodes={nodes}
                edges={edges}
                onNodesChange={onNodesChange}
                onEdgesChange={onEdgesChange}
                onConnect={onConnect}
                nodeTypes={nodeTypes}
            >
                <Controls />
                <MiniMap />
                <Background variant="dots" gap={12} size={1} />
            </ReactFlow>
        </div>
    );
}

I have no idea what can be wrong here.

I think you have not added a Handle to the custom node. You can review this section in the document in detail. Examine the ColorSelectorNode example in the document.
return (
    <>
      <Handle
        type="target"
        position={Position.Left}
        onConnect={(params) => console.log('handle onConnect', params)}
        isConnectable={isConnectable}
      />
       ...

